# How to pass parameter to anonymous function

Tags: php, parameters, parameter-passing, anonymous-function

I am using a library to track errors in our PHP application.

I copied and pasted a code they provided on how to initialize the library and integrated that on my class `__construct()` declaration:

```php
function __construct($username = null) {
    parent::__construct();

    if(SENTRY === true) {
        if(!empty($username)) {
            Sentry\configureScope(function (Sentry\State\Scope $scope): void {
                $scope->setUser(['username' => $username]);
            });
        } else if(!empty($_SESSION['username'])) {
            Sentry\configureScope(function (Sentry\State\Scope $scope): void {
                $scope->setUser(['username' => $_SESSION['username']]);
            });
        } else {
            Sentry\configureScope(function (Sentry\State\Scope $scope): void {
                $scope->setUser(['username' => null]);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Now I know I could always add the `$username` to the session and grab it from there and then maybe unset it after initializing the library but I'd rather not go that route. How do I pass the variable to the anonymous function when configuring the scope for the library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work by doing:

```php
Sentry\configureScope(function (Sentry\State\Scope $scope) use ($username) : void {
    if(!empty($username)) {
        $scope->setUser(['username' => $username]);
    } else if(!empty($_SESSION['username'])) {
        $scope->setUser(['username' => $_SESSION['username']]);
    } else {
        $scope->setUser(['username' => null]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$x = 123;
Sentry\configureScope(function (Sentry\State\Scope $scope) use($x) : void {
                // you may use $x
                $scope->setUser(['username' => $_SESSION['username']]);
            });
```